# why sys user do not see a user created by him

Tags: oracle

I am now learning Oracle, I created a user named gov and gave him access to the database, and the connection was made Question: When SYS tried other permissions from him, this message appeared to me after closing the old session and opening a new session. Please help me.

[image]

The picture above shows the error message

Comment: did you do create user gov or create user "gov" - those are two different users

Comment: Execute `SELECT * FROM DBA_USERS WHERE UPPER(USERNAME) = 'GOV'`. Let us know what you get back for results. Thanks.